# Linkedin Page Insights & Post Insights data

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-j

Is there something like Linkedin Page Comments, Page Shares, Page Impressions, Page Reactions, Page Clicks?

Also, the Update Analytics in Linkedin provide data regarding posts only?
When exporting data from Update Analytics it gives two tabs in excel file. Considering data was downloaded for the month of October.
Update Metrics gives data date-wise. Re-iterating, any activity(likes, shares, clicks etc.) happened with a post created in month of October or before will be recorded here. (pls confirm)
Update Engagement gives lifetime data post-wise. In this tab we have got lifetime of only those posts which were created in month of October. (pls confirm)

Update Metrics doesn't include any values that takes place with respect to page, as in Page Likes, Page Shares etc..

#linkedin